# Clustering of spatial data with maximum extension

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, dbscan

I am using DBSCAN to cluster my spatial geolocated data. However, some of the clusters that I find are really large, extending kilometers, which makes no sense for my application. The approach I am using is to run DBSCAN again with smaller epsilon, but is there any spatial clustering algorithm that tackles the question of partition/cluster spatial data with a maximum extent?

Answer (score 0):

Complete-linkage hierarchical clustering guarantees the maximum distance of any two points is below the given threshold.

There also is leader clustering, but it tends to be pretty bad.